# GKE CSIMigration

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have `CSI Driver` installed on **GKE** , I have `1.19 GKE` cluster version, I think , I have enabled `CSIMigration` feature-flag, but it does not seem to be working.

I have been trying to get a **volume snapshot created**, but I get error message saying:

`no underlying CSI physical volume found`.

How could I make **GKE** to enabled `feature gates` and `CSIMigragtionGCE`?

Comment: I don't think this will work as your PV is still technically configured using the non-CSI driver.  As I recall, CSI Migration works behind the scenes and redirects disk operations to the CSI Driver but does not actually modify the config of the PV itself.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an existing PersistentVolumeClaim to take a snapshot of and the PersistentVolume used for a snapshot source must be managed by a CSI driver.You can verify that you're using a CSI driver by checking that the PersistentVolume spec has a **csi** section with
**driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io**

If the PersistentVolume is [dynamically provisioned](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#dynamic_provisioning) by the CSI driver as described in the following sections, the CSI driver manages it.

Here are the documentations which has all other [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots#requirements) and detailed information on [Creating a VolumeSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots#creating_a_volumesnapshot)